# Frog Cross River - improving used data structures

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I was trying to do this exercice from codility:

A small frog wants to get to the other side of a river. The frog is currently located at position 0, and wants to get to position X. Leaves fall from a tree onto the surface of the river.

You are given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers representing the falling leaves. A[K] represents the position where one leaf falls at time K, measured in minutes.

The goal is to find the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river. The frog can cross only when leaves appear at every position across the river from 1 to X.

Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int solution(int X, int[] A); }
```

that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers and integer X, returns the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river.

If the frog is never able to jump to the other side of the river, the function should return −1.

**My solution**:

```
public int solution(int X, int[] A) {

        int[] vDestT = new int[A.length];
        int j = 0;
        // find times where X is visited
        // sort the array vDestT increasing order
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (A[i] == X && i > X - 1) {
                // put times  corresponding to requested destination X in vDestT in an increasing order
                if (j > 0 && i < vDestT[j - 1]) {
                    int temp = vDestT[j - 1];
                    vDestT[j - 1] = i;
                    vDestT[j] = temp;
                } else
                    vDestT[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }

        int k = 0;
        while (k < vDestT.length) {
            int remainP = X - 1;
            int remainT = vDestT[k] - 1;
            // check A[0..X-1]
            while (remainT >= remainP) {
                if (A[remainT] < X) {
                    remainP--;
                }
                if (remainP == 0)
                    return vDestT[k];
                remainT--;
            }
            if (remainT < remainP) {
                k++;
                continue;
            }

        }
        return -1;

    }
```

Well, it's the first solution that came to my mind (got 18/100 score) and would like to improve it, so I have some questions:
- By which structure should I replace **vDestT**?

-What are the conditions I missed(else than `if(A.length<X)  and if (A.length == 1 && X==1)`)?

**EDIT:** 
I thought that I have to find all times i where A[i] = X, put the "i"s in a sorted array increasing order. Starting with the 1st element from that array which I named vDestT, and see if I can get all the X-1 positions before that time, if not check the second time where A[i] = X. => A very complicated method, I don't know why I was convinced that I should get all times where A[i] = X and sort them in order to find the earliest time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, thank you but it's not a debugging help request.

Comment: "As many test cases didn't work" - that's what led me to believe that it was.  May I suggest you edit your question to remove all but the essentials.

Comment: I really don't understand what's not essentiel in it, as I'm asking about used structures, so I have to keep all the algorithm.

Comment: If you want help with your algorithm, you should explain your thoughts. E.g. I have no clue what the first loop is supposed to do. Maybe try to think of a simpler approach: You know the number of gaps that need to be filled by leaves. So you just need to count. And while counting, you have to detect duplicate leaves (that you don't want to count). Can you do this more efficiently than checking every other fallen leaf? Maybe by storing a boolean for every gap?

Comment: I thought that I have to find all times i where A[i] = X, put the "i"s in a sorted array increasing order. Starting with the 1st element from that array which I named vDestT, and see if I can get  all the X-1 positions before that time, if not check the second time where A[i] = X. => A very complicated method, I don't know what I was convinced that I should get all times where A[i] = X and sort them in order to find the earliest time.

Comment: @GuyCoder that's the language I know, but it can be done with any.

Comment: Of course! you can add them!

Comment: @GuyCoder It's neither though. [tag:java] and [tag:algorithm] both have plenty of followers, so there isn't much of an argument to add tags to give the question more attention (and Prolog, or any tag specifying a language not specific applicable to the question, is a bit of a stretch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to store all the times per location and then sort them, because you're only interested in the first one. Also, the input is chronological, so you may not need to check it all the way to the end.

- Create a data structure capable of storing X boolean values, and set them to false.
- Create a counter variable and set it to zero.
- Iterate over A, and for each time i, if the boolean for location A[i] is false, set it to true and increment the counter.
- As soon as the counter equals X, all locations are true, and time i is your answer.
- If at the end of A, the counter is less than X, some locations remain empty.

This way, you only iterate over the input once, and the answer is found in X to N steps, i.e. linear time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

You have an Array A which is implictly a collection of tuples (time,position), ordered by time. 
Populate a Set with all indices between 0 and X, and scan the Array which is conveniently in ascending order of time, subtract from the set any element seen. When the set is empty the path of leaves is complete. And the time point you reached is the earliest in which this possible. 
This takes linear time and linear extra space.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was—at least temporarily—tagged with [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog), I gather there may be some interest in a Prolog-based solution. Please note that with a suitable package for *constraints*, this approach may also be useful for a Java-based solution!

I am using Prolog to illustrate the overall idea: I will use a **constrained variable** to keep track of the indices where *water* is still flowing, i.e., places that are not (yet) covered by a leaf. Think about the variable's domain as representing the *uncovered* spots of the river.

Initially, the domain of the variable are the integers 1, 2, 3 ..., i.e., all integers I∈ [1,∞). Let us call the variable `Water`.

Assuming the availability of suitable constraints over **integers**, I can express the initial domain in Prolog as:

```
Water in 1..sup
```

This means that initially, all indices are *not yet covered* by a leaf.

I can indicate that a spot becomes covered by *removing* its index from the variable's domain.

For example:

```
?- Water in 1..sup,
   Water #\= 3,
   Water #\= 7.
```

This uses *disequality constraints*, stating that `Water` can *no longer attain* the values 3 and 7, and hence we regard such spots as *covered by leaves*. For the above query, Prolog answers:

```
Water in 1..2\/4..6\/8..sup.
```

This is simply a more compact way to state exactly the same thing.

Note that the *time complexity* of such an operation depends on your Prolog system. For example, GNU Prolog uses a *bitvector* representation when interior points are removed from a domain. This makes removing a single element an (amortized) **O(1)** operation!

It now remains to apply such disequality constraints in a systematic way, for all positions we are given, while keeping track of the current index.

A solution could look like this:

```
minutes_to_x(Leaves, X, Min) :-
        Water in 1..sup,
        to_x(Leaves, X, Water, 1, Min).

to_x([], _, _, _, -1).
to_x([L|Ls], X, Water, Index0, Min) :-
        Water #\= L,
        (   fd_inf(Water, Inf), Inf #> X ->
            Min #= Index0
        ;   Index #= Index0 + 1,
            to_x(Ls, X, Water, Index, Min)
        ).
```

Example queries and answers:

```
?- minutes_to_x([1,3,2], 1, Min).
Min = 1.

?- minutes_to_x([1,3,2], 2, Min).
Min = 3.

?- minutes_to_x([1,3,2], 3, Min).
Min = 3.

?- minutes_to_x([1,3,2], 4, Min).
Min = -1.
```

This is a **relation**, not a function, and so we use the last argument to hold the number of *minutes*.

The frog can move to position `X` as soon as the *infimum* of `Water` is greater than `X`, because this means that all spots from 1 to `X` are *covered* by leaves.